# difference in the two synchronized blocks in Java

Tags: java, synchronization

Let's say I have a class Employee and I create the object of that class as

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
```

What is the difference between the below two synchronized blocks

```
synchronized(emp){ } and
synchronized(Employee.class)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first one uses *one Employee instance* as monitor. The second one uses *the Employee class* as monitor.

If the goal is to guard instance variables of an employee, the first one is makes much more sense than the second one. If the goal is to guard static variables of the Employee class, the second one makes sense, but not the first one.

Comment: if we have 2 threads with two different instances(of Employee), the block will be entered by only one thread at a time.Am I right?

Comment: If each thread uses its own employee instance as monitor, they will synchronize on different monitors, and they will thus execute concurrently. One thread blocks another one if it holds an object's monitor and the other thread tries to obtain the SAME object's monitor.

Comment: I forgot to mention that above comment is for 2nd synchronized block i.e. synchronized(Employee.class)

Comment: There is only one Employee.class object (per classloader). So if both threads use Employee.class as monitor, they indeed block each other. Remember, though, that since Employee.class is available everywhere, any other, completely unrelated code could also choose to use it as monitor, which could lead to bad performance, or even deadlocks. I would use a private, final, encapsulated in a dedicated class, lock object to synchronize your threads.

Comment: Thanks JB for the nice explanation

Answer (score 1):

The first one synchronizes on specific instances of the class. So if you have 2 threads operating on two different instances of the class, they can both enter the block at the same time - within their own contexts, of course.

The second block synchronizes on the class itself. So even if you have 2 threads with two different instances, the block will be entered by only one thread at a time.

Answer (score 1):

When you syncrhonize, you need an object to define as the semaphore. When thread A is inside a syncrhonized block defined by object A, no other thread can be in other such a block defined by the object A, but it can be inside any other synchronized block defined by other objects.

`emp` and `Employee.class` are distinct objects, so the two synchronized blocks are not incompatible (you can have a thread inside the first and another inside the second).

In a more general note, you should use the first block to protect sensitive code that only affects to the individual employee objects, and the second one in operations where changing one employee may affect other employee critical section or a collection/aggregate value of them.